# Update query takes too much time with 26.4 million rows

Tags: mysql, time, sql-update

I have more than 26.4 million rows in table a "item"to be updated. i am using this query to update but it takes too much time aprox more than 4 hours and continue running. Is it correct query or there is better way to update it? Need your help

```
UPDATE item a
JOIN cost b ON a.order_id = b.order_id
           AND YEAR(a.date) = b.YEAR
           AND month(a.date) = b.month
           AND hour(a.time) = b.hour
SET a.cost = b.cost
```

query was obtained from below discussion it is running but taking too much time.

[Update table if conditions met. (update the value from table b to a) corresponding value required](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32305229/update-table-if-conditions-met-update-the-value-from-table-b-to-a-correspondi/32305260#32305260)

Comment: Is order_id a primary key?

Comment: order_id is not primary key but both tables are linked with order_id field (same field in both tables "item" & "cost")

Comment: How large is table `b`?  Perhaps 4 hours isn't so bad, if, for instance, all the rows are being updated.

Comment: Gordon Linoff-- table b "cost" have aroung 97K rows. time is 4 hours and continued